# sharepoint online list archival

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I want to know list archival methords specific to SharePoint Online/O365. I dont think record center will be applicable to SharePoint Online. I see workflow as the only solution to move the items to an archive list, but the problem I see here is I will not be able to update the metadata fields like CreatedBy , etc to the archive list as expected.

1. Does micorsoft suggent any ways of list item archival?
2. Any 3rd party tool for the same?
3. Microsoft suggest a list can hold up to 50 million records, what is the real significance, how does it affect the performance
4. If archived to a different list how does the workflow associated will get affect or can be handled ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you move list items between lists using the "Content and
   Structure" tool in Site Settings, the system fields such as created
   will be preserved, as the items are moved and not copied.

   In-Place record management of list items can be implemented by:
   Manual Declaration, Content Type Policies, List Workflows or
   Reusable Workflows.

   Record Center is used for documents and not list items, but is
   available in SharePoint Online.
2. Lots of pricy third-party solutions.
3. Haven't seen the 50 million figure, here is a lengthy response to dealing with [large lists in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784).

   4.Reusable Workflows will "handle" being used in multiple lists if configured properly.

   Personally, I recommend using content type policies that declare
   items in-place as records.